# Authenticity of uploaded pdf files

Tags: php, pdf, file-upload, security

My server must only accept pdf files. I am using php to upload files. Currently, I am checking if the file starts with %PDF to ensure the uploaded file really is a pdf file. Are there other checks to ensure 100%(or at least very strongly) that it is a pdf file. Can malicious users upload executable files beginning with %PDF? I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: if the file header is %PDF you can assume that you have a PDF file, if the pdf is a malicious one (means it uses an exploit of the reader to execute arbitrary code) is another story

Comment: You can use a PDF library of your choice and try to read the file as PDF. If it fails, it isn't a proper PDF file (by your library's terms).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the PECL [`FileInfo`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.fileinfo.php) extension to detect the MIME type. (I suspect however, that internally, it just does the same thing you're already doing.) Alternatively, you might use [`FPDI`](http://www.setasign.de/products/pdf-php-solutions/fpdi/) to see if you can successfully read the file. With PDF files though, I think embedded malware is a bigger concern than misnamed executables. Any time you're accepting uploads from users, it's probably a good idea to run the file through [`ClamAV`](http://www.clamav.net/lang/en/) or similar.