# check PDF files for javascript or other threads

Tags: php, pdf, exploit

I want to be able to detect if a PDF file uploaded by a user contains possible threats (JavaScript, System commands etc.) using PHP. I need a quick and easy way to do this. Can someone give me a simple example? Thank you very much.

Comment: Maybe the following SO q/a could be of help: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39615324/find-malicious-pdf-files-using-php-validation),  [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16928698/with-php-how-can-i-check-if-a-pdf-file-has-errors), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15773906/authenticity-of-uploaded-pdf-files)